# Toggle on CMS page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, cms

I'm completely new to magento so probably a quite basic question.
I've got some code for my cms page like this:

```
<div class="col2-Container"><div class="ResponsiveTest"><h3>Finder</h3>
<div class="ResponsiveTest2"><a href="http://www.somesite.co.uk”><img src=“…..” width="100%" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/></a>
<div class="button"><img src="{{media url=“….”}}” alt="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to get the functionality that when the user clicks on `.ResponsiveTest`  the div class `.ResponsiveTest2` is toggled.

To do that I've added this code to the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ResponsiveTest').observe('click', function() {
         $$('.ResponsiveTest2').each(function(item) {
             $(item).toggle();
         })
    })
</script>
```

This worked for a static block, but doesn't seem to work here. 
I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observe' of null

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('ResponsiveTest').observe('click', function() {
         $$('.ResponsiveTest2').each(function(item) {
             $(item).toggle();
         })
    })
</script>
```

Prototype js $ refere to id and $$ refere to class

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('.ResponsiveTest h3').each(function(element) {
        element.observe('click', function(element) {

            $$('.ResponsiveTest2').each(function(item) {
             item.toggle();
         });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to observe an element with an ID of `ResponsiveTest` and *not* a class.

You can either use:

`$$('responsivetest').observe('click', function() { ... }`

Or change your HTML like this:

`<div class="responsivetest" id="responsivetest"> ... </div>`

On a side note; I would *highly* recommend naming IDs and classes in lowecase - it'll make your life easier.